# How to match characters surrounded by special letters and/or parentheses?

Tags: python, regex

I was trying to write a regex statement in python but it is hard to capture '<<' and '«' at the same time.
The following regex is what I tried, but it doesn't capture as I want.

```
regex = "(<<)?«?{\w+}»?(>>)?(?=(\?|,|.|\s))"
```

With `regex` I tried to capture 3 types of strings.

1. <<{WORD}>>
2. «{WORD}»
3. {WORD}

```
    sent1 = "Do you want to eat «{Food}»? %[Y](A:y) %[N](A:n)"
    sent2 = "You were drinking <<{coldBeverage}>>, do you want to drink <<{hotBeverage}>> instead?"
    sent3 = "I am a {animal} who can talk."
```

I hope I could run the regex as followings:

```
    re.findall(regex, sent1) = ["«{Food}»"]
    re.findall(regex, sent2) = ["<<{coldBeverage}>>", "<<{hotBeverage}>>"]
    re.findall(regex, sent3) = ["{animal}"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If our samples might be just limited to those listed, we can start with this expression:

```
(«{[^»]+»|<<{[^>]+>>|{[^}]+})
```

#### Test with `re.finditer`

```
import re

regex = r"(«{[^»]+»|<<{[^>]+>>|{[^}]+})"

test_str = ("    sent1 = \"Do you want to eat «{Food}»? %[Y](A:y) %[N](A:n)\"\n"
    "    sent2 = \"You were drinking <<{coldBeverage}>>, do you want to drink <<{hotBeverage}>> instead?\"\n"
    "    sent3 = \"I am a {animal} who can talk.\"\n\n"
    " re.findall(regex, sent1) = [\"«{Food}»\"]\n"
    "    re.findall(regex, sent2) = [\"<<{coldBeverage}>>\", \"<<{hotBeverage}>>\"]\n"
    "    re.findall(regex, sent3) = [\"{animal}\"]")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```

#### Test with `re.findall`

```
import re

regex = r"(«{[^»]+»|<<{[^>]+>>|{[^}]+})"

test_str = ("    sent1 = \"Do you want to eat «{Food}»? %[Y](A:y) %[N](A:n)\"\n"
    "    sent2 = \"You were drinking <<{coldBeverage}>>, do you want to drink <<{hotBeverage}>> instead?\"\n"
    "    sent3 = \"I am a {animal} who can talk.\"\n\n"
    " re.findall(regex, sent1) = [\"«{Food}»\"]\n"
    "    re.findall(regex, sent2) = [\"<<{coldBeverage}>>\", \"<<{hotBeverage}>>\"]\n"
    "    re.findall(regex, sent3) = [\"{animal}\"]")

print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

---

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/DmqKRi/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/DmqKRi/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs step by step, if you like.

Comment: Think about `[^>>]`... what does it do?